# Histogram in ggplot2 with pre-defined probability values

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to make my own histogram in ggplot2 where I supply ggplot2 with the probability for each value of the parameter values in a vector instead of having it calculate the probability values itself from a single vector.

Toy data:

This is the parameter values

```
p <- seq(from = 0.05, to = 0.95, by = 0.1)
```

I assign each of these a weight

```
prior <- c(1, 5.2, 8, 7.2, 4.6, 2.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0, 0)
```

Then calculate a prior probability for each of these weights

```
prior <- prior/sum(prior)
```

Now using the `plot()` function we can create a histogram using those two vectors

```
plot(p, prior, "h", ylab = "prior probability")
```

But how can I get a similar graph in ggplot2?

If I try putting these into a dataframe

```
gDF <- data.frame(p = p, priorProb = prior)
```

Then graphing it

```
ggplot(gDF, aes(x = p, y = priorProb)) + geom_histogram()
```

I get the error `Error: stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic`, which makes sense because usually for a histogram ggplot only uses a single vector.

Any help appeciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ggplot(gDF, aes(x = p, y = priorProb)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: Looks]

Comment: Ah yes. So obvious. Thinking rigidly I was. And i guess you could use a `width = 0.01` argument within the `geom_bar()` to get the bars to look more like the histogram bars in the  `plot("h")` function. Thank you @Nathan Day.